# Editor is shown at full width

Tags: editor

The title field and all editor is full width. I don't know where to start looking. Any clue is welcome.

All plugins deactivated.

[image]

Comment: "All plugins deactivated" - have you tried switching to a default theme like 2021?

Comment: looks like your theme doesn't provide an editor stylesheet that gives the main content area a maximum width, or, you have a very big content width set that's much wider than your computers screen, you should contact the authors of your theme

Comment: Correct. It is a theme issue, sorry. Is the default behavior of Sage 10 starter theme. I 'll answer the question as soon I learn how to do it exactly. It has to do with defining containers in theme.json

Answer (score 1):

As [theme handbook said](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/theme-json/#layout), I have to define the containers in the theme.json

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "settings": {
        "layout": {
            "contentSize": "840px",
            "wideSize": "1100px"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing - that's quite helpful  :)